# Как работать с библиотекой php-telegram-bot/laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, telegram

Проблема в том, что я не вижу никакой внятной документации по тому, как работать с этой библиотекой. Поставил, создал команды, запустил :fetch. Данные получаю, в базу они пишутся, но как это обрабатывать и отдавать в бота не понятно. Также как и непонятно, как принимать данные в вебхук. Если кто-то работал с этим, направьте пожалуйста в нужном направлении.

Comment: Скорее всего это просто обертка над `php-telegram-bot/core`, поэтому кроме вызова фасада методы ничем не будут отличаться. Но я бы Вам советовал перейти на https://github.com/defstudio/telegraph, тут и с документацией всё в порядке, и над пакетом прям работают, а не обновляют раз в полгода

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю!